# Pandas ExtensionDtype / ExtensionArray custom format for to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In [pandas extension interface](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#extension-types) (`ExtensionDtype` + `ExtensionArray`), is it possible to use a custom formatting when calling the `to_csv` function on a `Series` or a `DataFrame` which contains column of such a type?

It seems that the `to_csv` function will somehow call the `__str__` function of the underlying scalar type object. However, I definitely want different formatting behavior between a call from `str()` and from `to_csv`.

In the [ExtensionArray documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html#pandas-api-extensions-extensionarray) we can find:

```
One can implement methods to handle parsing from strings that will be used in methods such as pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.

  - _from_sequence_of_strings
```

And I'm perfectly fine with it, but this is for **reading** from a string, not for **writing** it.

Comment: What is the question? Do you have a [mcve] supporting your problem? What would be the expected output then?

Comment: Any chance you will add more context or better a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer.

Having a better description of what you want to achieve would help a lot in the resolution.
Feel free to update your post to meet the stack standards.

#### Bleeding edge potentially breaking feature

First notice objects you are citing are fairly new and may introduces breaking change in your flows:

> The `pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype` and
> `pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray` APIs are **new** and **experimental**.
> They may change between versions without warning.

It always nice to get on the bandwagon. But maybe your proactive approach is demanding more than `pandas` can at the very moment.

#### Dive into `pandas` source

Notice than `pandas` heavily rely on python object model and introspection, it also performs a lot of substitutions.

```
import inspect
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__  # 1.3.5
```

For instance, finding the source of `read_csv` is not straightforward:

```
inspect.getsourcefile(pd.read_csv)
# ./pandas/util/_decorators.py
```

This is out of luck, but the source still can be reached:

```
inspect.getsource(pd.read_csv)
```

And this explains why we are routed to `_decorator.py`:

```
@deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments(
    version=None, allowed_args=["filepath_or_buffer"], stacklevel=3
)
# ...
def read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer: FilePathOrBuffer,
# ...
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
```

With a bit of search, you may find the file on [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/66e3805b8cabe977f40c05259cc3fcf7ead5687d/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L502-L586).

#### Checking future `Extension` objects

Reading the source of [`ExtensionDtype`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/dtypes/base.py#L35-L368) and [`ExtensionArray`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/arrays/base.py#L90-L1324) exposes specific conversion methods.

As spotted on by @sneakers-the-rat, there is a [`_formatter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/arrays/base.py#L1178-L1204) method in `ExtensionArray` that might be a good try once we know what you aim to achieve.

#### Exploring the `to_csv` stack

This method is more easy to find, but it has a lot of indirection levels. You can explore it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/66e3805b8cabe977f40c05259cc3fcf7ead5687d/pandas/core/generic.py#L3297-L3483). The key point is it returns a `DataFrameRenderer` object:

```
@final
@doc(storage_options=_shared_docs["storage_options"])
def to_csv(
    self,
    path_or_buf: FilePathOrBuffer[AnyStr] | None = None,
    # ...
):
    # ...
    return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
        # ...
    )
```

Which is defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/66e3805b8cabe977f40c05259cc3fcf7ead5687d/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1056-L1113) and also makes use of a `CSVFormatter` object defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/66e3805b8cabe977f40c05259cc3fcf7ead5687d/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py#L45-L317).

This final object contains the whole logic to convert a `DataFrame` into a CSV file. But it does not make any **explicit use** of:

- `ExtensionDtype` or `ExtensionArray` objects or object methods;
- string conversion using `str` or `repr` or related magic methods `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

#### Intermediate conclusions

This is not an exhaustive search nor a proof that it is not feasible, but this is strongly dependent of the goal you want to achieve. A more precise definition would help towards a solution.

This answer is based on latest version (`1.3.5`) at the time of writing. Pandas framework moves fast.

Extending pandas using their own framework is certainly a good idea. Anyway it seems for the moment that you will have to wait for:

- Extension objects to expose export functionalities as well as import;
- Conversions functionalities to be mapped in export flows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to override the `_formatter` method

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5b2f4a531f38b8cc8a0b372aeae09c1d94fc99e8/pandas/core/arrays/base.py#L1248-L1274

By default it just calls `str` on the array, but you can override it to be whatever you want as long as it returns a callable that takes the object to a string.

`_formatter` is used within `io.formats.format.format_array` any anytime a string representation is requested.

`to_csv` uses the `iget_values` method of the `ArrayManager`, which I believe is what you'd have to write, but `to_csv` also converts arrays to native types first, so you may have to just override that too.

Would be able to answer this with more detail -- MRE as well as on what you're calling to_csv.

here's `_formatter` just to show how simple it is:

```py
    def _formatter(self, boxed: bool = False) -> Callable[[Any], str | None]:
        """
        Formatting function for scalar values.
        This is used in the default '__repr__'. The returned formatting
        function receives instances of your scalar type.
        Parameters
        ----------
        boxed : bool, default False
            An indicated for whether or not your array is being printed
            within a Series, DataFrame, or Index (True), or just by
            itself (False). This may be useful if you want scalar values
            to appear differently within a Series versus on its own (e.g.
            quoted or not).
        Returns
        -------
        Callable[[Any], str]
            A callable that gets instances of the scalar type and
            returns a string. By default, :func:`repr` is used
            when ``boxed=False`` and :func:`str` is used when
            ``boxed=True``.
        """
        if boxed:
            return str
        return repr
```